# Scala: Erroneous type mismatch error using ArrayList

Tags: java, scala, type-inference, scala-collections

Can anyone explain why the following error occurs (Scala 2.10.3)?

```
scala> new java.util.ArrayList[Integer]()
res0: java.util.ArrayList[Integer] = []

scala> res0.add(0)
res1: Boolean = true

scala> java.util.Collections.binarySearch(res0, 0)
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.ArrayList[Integer]
 required: java.util.List[_ <: Comparable[_ >: Any]]
              java.util.Collections.binarySearch(res0, 0)
                                                 ^
```

The following does work:

```
scala> java.util.Collections.binarySearch[Integer](res0, 0)
res4: Int = 0
```

It seems odd that the compiler would complain about a particular type until I was *more explicit* about that incorrect type and then it will accept it.

EDIT:

Also note the if you change the first step to:

```
scala> new java.util.ArrayList[Int]()
```

there is also a very similar error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
java.util.Collections.binarySearch(res0, 0: Integer)
```

As you can see, it compiles fine.
The problem was that `0` has type `Int`, not `Integer`. So you have to tell scala somehow that you want to convert `0` into a `Integer` value.

As it stands, your code triggers the compiler to look for a method `binarySearch` which takes and `ArrayList[Integer]` as its first parameter, and an `Int` as its second parameter.

Comment: Makes sense, but I'm still not sure I understand the logic of the message. Is it that `Integer` doesn't conform to `_ <: Comparable[_ >: Any]`, but `Int` does?

Comment: Well the compiler does not know if the error comes from the type of the first parameter, or from the type of the second (or both). 
All it can tell is that this combination of types is invalid (there is no method `binarySearch` which can take an `ArrayList[Integer]` as its first aprameter and an `Int` as its second one. Granted, it may be nicer if the compiler just said it cannot make the call given the input types, 
rather than emiting a message that can lead you to think that only the first parameter is faulty.

Comment: But if I do the exact same steps, just changing the initial `List` creation to `new java.util.ArrayList[Int]()`, I get the same error! Shouldn't that work by your explanation? Thanks.

Comment: `java.util.ArrayList[Int]` does not conform to `java.util.List[_ <: java.lang.Comparable[_ >: Any]]` simply because `Int` is not a sub-type of `java.lang.Comparable` (but `java.lang.Integer` is).
So the compiler is entrely right to complain if you pass an instance of `java.util.ArrayList[Int]` to `binarySearch`

Answer (score 0):

Definition of `binarySearch` is as follows:

> Searches the specified list for the specified object using the binary search algorithm.

```
static <T> int
binarySearch(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> list, T key)
```

As you can see, `list` and `key` are parameterized on a type `T`. Now Scala compiler tries to infer the type of `list` in following invocation:

```
scala> java.util.Collections.binarySearch(l, 0)
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.ArrayList[Integer]
 required: java.util.List[_ <: Comparable[_ >: Any]]
              java.util.Collections.binarySearch(l, 0)
```

And the common type between the parameters `list` and `key` is `Any`. Because former is of type `List<Integer>` and later is of type `int` as per Java. So this converts in Scala to `Integer` and `int` respectively, as explained below:

```
scala> classOf[Integer]
res9: Class[Integer] = class java.lang.Integer

scala> classOf[Int]
res10: Class[Int] = int
```

Comment: @david: Yes, it makes much sense now :-)